# MarmaladeSDK: How to create a project in XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode, marmalade

I've created FirstProgram.mkb with the following content:

```
files
{
    (source)
    HelloWorld.cpp
}

subprojects
{
    iwgx
}
```

I started it with XCode 4.6 and it opens it as a text file. What do I do wrong? How to create a marmalade sdk project in XCode?

I don't need MarmaladeQuick cause I need to use C++ (not Lua as for Quick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just double click on the `mkb` file and if it asks, use `mkb.app` found in `/Developer/Marmalade/6.3/Applications` to open the file. The mkb script will automatically create an XCode project for you and will open it in XCode too.
Just remember, never open the XCode project directly. You should always double click on mkb to open XCode, since it updates the XCode project files when needed.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to save the hierarchy of my folders in XCode when I reopen my MKB? I wish source files place in the source directories in XCode. I do it by my hands in XCode but when I reopen my MKB - all source files in the root of the XCode again... How can I solve it?

Comment: Opening MKBs will always reset the XCode project file(Same with Visual Studio on a PC). So the hierarchy needs to be saved in the mkb itself. If you want to create a folder/group for your files, you need to specify it like this   
 (Source/system) //Specifies the actual folder system in Finder
 ["Source" , "System"] //Specifies the group in XCode.
You can find more info on Marmalade Docs in mkb references.

Comment: FYI there're some good beginner tutorials written by matth on http://www.drmop.com/index.php/marmalade-sdk-tutorials/. You should have a look at them. I am also in the process of writing some tutorials too, You can find link at my userpage when I am done.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one Marmalade version installed, you need to be careful of associating .mkb files with the mkb.app. My experience on Macs is that this overrides the s3e_config settings. I'm planning to write a script that picks up the s3e_config setting but for the moment I would advise using the command line shell: cd to the appropriate directory and then do "mkb foobar.mkb" or whatever.

[FTR Contrast with the PC situation where s3eConfig.exe sets up the GUI but not the command line!]